# selenium python - assign value to a variable from web page

Tags: python, html, selenium, innerhtml

[tried this method did not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14QLf.png)

how can i assign the value of an element from web page to a variable using selenium python in pycharm
data structure

250

a=driver.get.element(By.ID,"rate").text()

250

a=driver.get.element(By.ID,"rate").innerHTML()

Comment: data structure

<span id=rate>250</span>

Comment: What is pycharm data structure?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using `text` instead of `text()`

Comment: <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_Heads_lbl_NetWeight_0">574.05855</span>    i want to get 574.05855 and assign this to a variable in my code

Comment: weight = driver.find_element(By.ID,"ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_Heads_lbl_NetWeight_0").text

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PC\PYPROJECT\venv\roundup.py", line 14, in <module>
    weight = driver.find_element(By.ID,"ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_Heads_lbl_NetWeight_0").text
NameError: name 'driver' is not defined

Comment: this error is showing when used text

Comment: what is driver here? is it assigned?

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\\___\\drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=opt)

Comment: i inserted the find element line below driver assignment line and force converted the text value into float and it is working now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\___\drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=opt)

weight1 = driver.find_element(By.ID,"ContentPlaceHolder1_grd_Heads_lbl_NetWeight_0").text
weight2 = float(weight1)